# apply cloth with different body

Tags: mesh, objects

there is a tight cloth which I want to apply to a body

but the cloth shape is different since the cloth comes from the different body.

I tried to fit it as much as possible and used sculpt painting,

but it ruins the texture alot.

is there any other way to fit cloth to the body?

sorry I'm still new to blender.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simulating the cloth object as "cloth" in the Physics panel? It'll make the object behave like real cloth. Set the cloth as "cloth" and the body as "collision", and press the "Play" button in the timeframe, and it should go well.

Comment: I am not talking about the animation. and even if I tried cloth and collision it doesn't work because the cloth doesn't fit with the body at all, and it actually causes the cloth just break apart and fall down. maybe tweak cloth mesh to fit the body shape can be the solution, but its gonna be a hard work since there's alot to do.

Comment: JKIM, could you please upload a .blend file? I'll see what I can do.